# Open Telegram chat of specific user with text message via browser link

Tags: telegram

I would like to know if via a Browser URL I can open the Telegram chat of a specific user and at the same time pre fill the first message with a text passt over the URL.

I know that I can open the chat of a user via this link format:

```
https://t.me/username
```

Now the only thing missing is how to pass a text message. For example like this:

```
https://t.me/username?text=example
```

Comment: really really want this feature

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible as of October 2022. You can only share a URL to a user and add a message there. The only thing I found. WhatsApp does it, Telegramm not. It would be a simple code in the Android app for instance, that would open the URL scheme, but it's not implemented