# Is it possible to create a telegram and viber link to a specific chat with a pre filled message?

Tags: telegram, whatsapp, viber

There are a few conversations on stackoverflow on this subject but solutions from them are not working.
For example this one [Pre-filled message to a Telegram number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58717593/pre-filled-message-to-a-telegram-number)

And in the link below it is said that there is no such feature for telegram, but this not entirely true (read below).
[Open Telegram chat of specific user with text message via browser link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69837957/open-telegram-chat-of-specific-user-with-text-message-via-browser-link)

I know that in **whatsapp** you can do it in this way

whatsapp://send?phone=1234567890&text=Hello%20World

and there is something similar in **telegram**, so the link looks like this

tg://msg?to=@username&text=Hello%20World

but it works only if I open the link on phone.

And for **viber** I've tried something like this

viber://forward?text=Hello%20World&recipient=+1234567890

but it doesn't work at all.

**1. So, is it possible to create in telegram such link that will work for both pc and phone devices?
2. And is it possible to create similar link for viber?**

Answer (score 0):

**First**. In your info.plist should contains

```xml
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
  <array>
    <string>whatsapp</string>
    <string>viber</string>
    <string>tg</string>
    <string>itms-beta</string>
    <string>itms</string>
</array>
```

**Second**. Your url link should be like this: `viber://chat?number=1234567890&draft=Hello%20World`